# How to go about creating an application for silverlight(desktop & web) as well as WP7?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Right now I'm creating an application for WP7 and have recieved alot of feedback about creating a similar application (if not the same) for the desktop as well as the web.

I have a few question about migrating an application from WP7 to the desktop with silverlight, and to the web with silverlight because I know that the feature sets between them are somewhat similar as well different (ex Controls, Classes):

- Are there resources on getting
  started with this type of development
  projects?
- What methods are available for accomplishing this kind of project, for example creating reusable code libraries?
- Is it better to start of with one platform over the other?
- Does VisualStudio have project templates designed for this type of development?

Keep in mind this is a first for me, so any tips, gotchas, references, or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some resources:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/FlashcardsShow-84f2b3ba

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2011/02/17/flashcards-show-version-2-for-the-desktop-browser-and-windows-phone.aspx

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/03/03/flashcards-show-planning-a-cross-platform-solution.aspx

Comment: These are great resources, plus there up to date. Will get back after I try them out.

Answer (score 3):

You can reuse all of your application logic.  The [Portable Library Tools CTP](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/) simplifies this greatly, as it lets you target a "least common denominator" across all of the platforms in question.

Your Views will likely need some customization as the screen real estate and controls are quite different on desktop vs. phone, however.